# Problem with Remarketing Audiences sample code

Tags: python, google-analytics-api

I am having problems with the sample code shown here (python version):

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/remarketingAudience/list

I am having trouble with this bit:

```
except TypeError, error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error

except HttpError, error:
  # Handle API errors.
  print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %
         (error.resp.status, error.resp.reason))
```

ERROR:

```
    except TypeError, error:
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I am just beginning with Python, but it seems to be that the sample code in the above-mentioned link is using python2, so I had to make some amendments (like encapsulating every 'print' with parenthesis). Could it be something of that sort? I couldn't find another way to write these ones.

I bet it's something really silly, but I can't quite fix it! Many thanks in advance.

Comment: please share your code that you have amended

Comment: what do you mean exactly? the part of the code that is giving me trouble is the one i quoted in the first box, there rest can be found in the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the tool `2to3`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/2to3.html) for this kind of thing. Here's a snippet of that example code after running `2to3 -w example.py`, where `example.py` is a file containing the python example code at that link you provided.

```
try:
  audiences = analytics.management().remarketingAudience().list(
      accountId='123456',
      webPropertyId='UA-123456-1'
  ).execute()

except TypeError as error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print('There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error)

except HttpError as error:
  # Handle API errors.
  print(('There was an API error : %s : %s' %
         (error.resp.status, error.resp.reason)))

...
```

`HttpError, error` isn't valid syntax after the `except` in Python 3